# Use returned subscribed data of an observable in a service from multiple component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm unable to get the returned data of my observable which is subscribed in service and the same is called in multiple components.

```
global.service.ts: 

sendProducts(){
   return this.getProducts().subscribe(response => {
     // perform some logic and return the output
      return data;
 });
}

getProducts(): Observable {
this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(map(resp => resp));
}
```

Now from multiple components, I want to access this data from my `sendProducts()` method and it is coming as undefined

```
products.component.ts

getProducts() {
   const productsList = this.globalService.sendProducts();
   console.log(productsList) => it is coming as undefined.
}
```

My required output is to get that returned data in components

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your service, the `sendProducts()` method returns a `Subscription` rather than an `Observable`.

It is not necessary to `subscribe` in order to "*perform some logic and return the output*".  You can instead use many different "[pipeable operators](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators)" to transform the emitted values and run other code:

- `map` - transforms data using the function you provide
- `tap` - is for doing any type of "side-effect" type of logic.  This does not affect what is returned
- There are many, many, more operators for transforming, filtering, repeating, etc that you can use to suit your needs.

**Service:**

```
sendProducts() {
   return this.getProducts().pipe(
        tap(products => console.log('perform some logic...', products),
        map(products => ([...products, { id: 0, name: 'Default Product' }]))
   );
}
```

Then in your component:
**Component:**

```
getProducts() {
   this.globalService.sendProducts().subscribe(
       productsList => console.log(productsList)
   );
}
```

But then how do you use that data (`productsList`) ?

You may be inclined to do something like this:

```
public products: Product[];

getProducts() {
   this.globalService.sendProducts().subscribe(
       productsList => this.products = productsList
   );
}
```

But you could get away with not subscribing at all, even in your component and do something like this:

```
public products$ = this.globalService.sendProducts();
```

Then in your template, use the `async` pipe to handle subscribing for you:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let product of products$ | async ">{{ product.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

The second approach results in less code :-)

Comment: is there a way to use the second approach in ts file ?

Comment: You mean in component?  Yes. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `getProducts()` should be the one to have the return
2. Just call one function in your `global.service.ts`. Chances are the flow is asynchronous

Your `getProducts()` in `global.service.ts` should be:

```
getProducts() {
  return this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(map(resp => resp));
}
```

And you `getProducts()` in your `product.component.ts`

```
getProducts() {
  this.globalService.getProducts().subscribe(
     response => {
       console.log(response) //see your data here
     }, err => console.error(err)
  );
}
```

cleaner code and more understandable